# Nautilus does not launch

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, files, filemanager

For some reason, nautilus stopped working properly. I am on Ubuntu 20.04. Rebooting does not help, as some advices I found on the web. When I launch nautilus in GUI it thinks for a minute and then nothing happens. When I try to run it from terminal using `nautilus` command it just hangs. Only `sudo nautilus` works. But when I launch it using `sudo` it does not show all the folders. Can anyone help? Please.

P.S. I forgot to add that nautilus works for guest user I've created.

[image]

Comment: That's because `sudo nautilus` is a bad command. Now some nautilus settings are owned by `root` and it doesn't start. After you fix it, never run nautilus with sudo.

Comment: I never launched nautilus with sudo before it broke down. Only after I was unable to launch it from GUI, and from terminal I launched it with sudo. So it might add problems, but it is not the original reason.

Comment: Strange: bookmarks are not supposed to be in `.gtk-bookmarks` but in `.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.

Comment: this might be because I launched it with `sudo`

Comment: so far i've installed Thunar and living with it, because I did not find a solution.

Comment: I might attempt `sudo ls -la /root/ | grep bookmarks` and when it runs okay but does not return anything, then I might attempt `sudo touch /root/.gtk-bookmarks` and see what happens next time when I try opening nautilus... Just an uninformed idea.

Comment: Does Nautilus also hang when your computer is offline, not connected to any LAN or WLAN?

Comment: What does `G_DEBUG="all" NAUTILUS_DEBUG="All" nautilus` from terminal tell you? Tried to reset nautilus with `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.nautilus`? This would reset all nautilus settings listed in `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.nautilus`.

Comment: `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG="all" NAUTILUS_DEBUG="Window" nautilus` should give you some more information. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1220 - The log file will be saved in your $home folder.

Comment: thanks to @starkus I was able to get some debug info from nautilus, but I have no clue what to do with it. https://imgur.com/DvkoZfT

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like a tracker error to me. And/or maybe your locales need to be reconfigured. Did you try resetting your tracker? Maybe reinstalling it?

Comment: thank you very much.  Resting tracker config to defaults with`tracker reset -c` helped. If you care to add an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to starkus in the comment section I was able to get some debug information using:

```
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG="all" NAUTILUS_DEBUG="Window" nautilus
```

I got the following info:
[image]

Then starkus suggested that something might be wrong with tracker. So reseting tracker settings with

```
tracker reset -c
```

solved the problem.